# MySQL: How to insert multiple rows into one table for each id of another query?

Tags: mysql

I have a key-value table and I need to insert multiple rows for each selected `id` from another table.

1. I get the user id:

   ```
   SELECT @id := id FROM user WHERE email = 'my@email.com';
   ```
2. I get the ids of things by user id:

   ```
   SELECT @things := id FROM `things` WHERE `owner_id` = @id;
   ```
3. Now I need to insert multiple values into key-value table for each `@things`. And problem here is that I cannot use a select subquery, because I need to insert inline values, like:

   ```
   INSERT INTO key_value (key, value)
   VALUES (
       @things, 'CUSTOM VALUE 1'
   ),
   VALUES (
       @things, 'CUSTOM VALUE 2'
   );
   ```

BUT, it does not work. The last query is obviously wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

---

#### EDIT:

Looks like I need multiple queries to do that:

```
SELECT @id := id FROM user WHERE email = 'startour@netron.no';

INSERT INTO key_value (`key`, `value`)
(
    SELECT id, 'CUSTOM_VALUE_1'
    FROM `things`
    WHERE `owner_id` = @id
);

INSERT INTO key_value (`key`, `value`)
(
    SELECT id, 'CUSTOM_VALUE_2'
    FROM `things`
    WHERE `owner_id` = @id
);
```

Comment: This is completely upside down. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, it help migrating DB data and structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO key_value (key, value)
SELECT user.id as key, things.id as value FROM user
left outer join things on  user.id=things.owner_id
 WHERE user.email = 'my@email.com'
```

Comment: Thanks, helps a bit, but I need custom values, not selected ones. So basically it's 2 rows insert, per `things.id`.

Comment: So @Aleksandr, (and ignoring weaknesses of the design) just use two inserts, along the lines Vikram's described above.

Comment: @Strawberry, yeah, that's the way we gonna go. Thanks.